# how to remove docker completely in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I tried to completely remove the docker in Ubuntu by following  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313851/2340159)  . But it is not working. After uninstalling the docker, I can get access to the docker.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: First stop and disable the docker service then remove it.